# Installing Fedora using Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I recently got a new hard drive and I want to install Fedora to it however the computer is old and can't boot from USB and I am unable to use a DVD.

I want to use my currently installed Fedora to install a new copy on the new hard drive.

I have the ISO with me. I am using the latest distro

Are there any ways I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to boot an iso with syslinux

just for example from my syslinux.cfg,

```
LABEL slitaz.iso
    LINUX memdisk
    INITRD /slitaz.iso
    APPEND iso
```

in the example, the iso (`slitaz.iso`) is in the root (`/`). I cannot tell on oath that will work for your iso, but you can try.

I did that too with grub,

```
setparams 'ISO'

    set iso ="/slitaz.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.53-slitaz
    initrd (loop)/boot/rootfs.gz
```

the two lines with (loop) are the one you can found inside your iso.

I don't remember if I had to install or set something for one or both cases.